# Is there a way to make user only able to use a specified app on an Android device without rooting?

Tags: android, fullscreen, promotions

For example, it's for promotions or events. Therefore I want users not able to leave our app.  For iOS, i guess I can make a frame to physically block the main button. But for Android, i don't know how.

Comment: you need a kiosk mode

Comment: If you know which device you have, you can block the navigation buttons as well.

Comment: @blackbelt if he talks about a "physical frame" to block the iOS home button, the same would be possible for an Android device. You just need to block the on screen system navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. It is scheduled to be included in the upcoming L release. See [Task locking](http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html).

"The L Developer Preview introduces a new task locking API that lets you temporarily restrict users from leaving your app or being interrupted by notifications. This could be used, for example, if you are developing an education app to support high stakes assessment requirements on Android. Once your app activates this mode, users will not be able to see notifications, access other apps, or return to the Home screen, until your app exits the mode."